# inventory management system database

Tags: database-design

I'm making an inventory management system using invoices.

- creating invoices (sale/transfer between warehouses or purchase)

  if purchasing new product => we will define new products in database

  we have currencies, units, account agent (supplier or customer) ...

  system will be able to add/modify delete all data(products,currencies,units

if someone of you have a business ideas please help me

 this is an example of invoice teacher gave me
[image: this is an example of an invoice]

my db diagram is as follows

[image]
can u help me if there is a lack? because my teacher is waiting for something bigger than my entity and he is not telling me what to do more or helping to add more attributes.

**where should i put tva?

should i put tva final of all items in invoice table?

should i put the net amount in invoice table?

are the relationship true?**